# ImportError: No module named gasp is there any file i need to download in order to perform?

Tags: python

im new to python gasp .
im wondering do i need extra add-on module for python so it could work? like a module file or something.

my code that i was just trying to see whether it works:
    from gasp import*

```
begin_graphics(800,600,"My Game",color.YELLOW)

end_graphics()
```

and it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\testing idle codes\GASP", line 1, in <module>
    from gasp import*
ImportError: No module named gasp
```

if is a file that needed to download. please guide me. im using window 7 32bit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see http://dev.laptop.org/pub/gasp/downloads/ for what to get for your platform.

Comment: that pygame download only capable for 2.+ python rite? i downloaded python 3. do i have to downgrade it?

Comment: Yes, `pygame` and `gasp` are for Python 2 only; get the lastest version of Python 2.7 for your platform. Remember to accept an answer if it solved your problem.